# How to add items to the item List in PayPal API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal

i am a little new to MVC. But I've come a long way. i integrated the PayPal MVC API into my project, and i realized when i threw multiple items in my cart and check out the items list only populates with the latest item in the array.

I've been trying to play with this bu i readily don't know  what I'm missing with adding multiple items to the item list in PayPal.

There's this part in PaymentWithCreditCard():

```
        //create and item for which you are taking payment
        //if you need to add more items in the list
        //Then you will need to create multiple item objects or use some loop to instantiate object
        var item = new Item();
        foreach (var cartitem in cookieCarts)
        {
            item.name = cartitem.Fullname;
            item.currency = "USD";
            item.price = cartitem.Price;
            item.quantity = cartitem.Qty.ToString();
            item.sku = cartitem.Sku;
            var intPrice = Int32.Parse(cartitem.Price);
            subtotal = subtotal + intPrice;
        }

        //Now make a List of Item and add the above item to it
        //you can create as many items as you want and add to this list
        var itms = new List<Item>();
        itms.Add(item);
        var itemList = new ItemList();
        itemList.items = itms;
```

im not sure how to go about adding my forloop into the item list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@NeoSketo try this. Also, I don't see what the subtotal is doing so i left it alone.

```
            List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

            foreach (var cartitem in cookieCarts)
            {                    
                items.Add(new Item {
                    name = cartitem.FullName,
                    currency = "USD",
                    price = cartitem.Price,
                    sku = cartitem.Sku,
                    quantity = cartitem.Qty.ToString()
                });

                var intPrice = Int32.Parse(cartitem.Price);
                subtotal = sobtotal + intPrice;
            }

            ItemList theItemList = new ItemList();
            theItemList.items = new List<Item>();
            theItemList.items = items;
```

Comment: nice! much appreciation! i see there! Yeah the subtotal was  just tallying up the price by iteration.